# How to control export of records in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, module, record

With the following sample module:

```
module Exp ( initial, myval ) where
data State = State { i :: Int }
initial = State { i = 123 }
myval st = i st
```

After I load the module in GHCI, I can see that the `State` and `i` names have also been exported. I can get their types and use them. How do I limit the export so that only `initial` (a black box) and `myval` are exported?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`State` and `i` are not exported, but if you load an *interpreted* module in ghci, then all top-level definitions of that module are in scope. To hide what you didn't export from ghci, compile the module and load the compiled module, `:l Exp` resp `ghci Exp`. Then only the exported entities are available.